# Is stationarity of variables neccessary condition for Bayesian VAR?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, stationarity, vector-autoregression, hierarchical-bayesian

I am trying to run a BVAR on 5 variables. Four out of five are non-stationary. So shall I do the first difference of the non-stationarity variables or take them in level for running the BVAR?

And what are diagnostic tests I can perform on BVAR estimation?

The online resource on BVAR is lacking.

Comment: Google yields quite a few hits for "Bayesian VAR" including lecture notes and academic papers.

Comment: A BVAR is basically a VAR, so stationarity still applies. Some quick links: 
- https://www.r-econometrics.com/timeseries/bvar/
- https://eviews.com/EViews8/ev8ecbvar_n.html
- https://blog.eviews.com/2019/06/bayesian-var-prior-comparison.html